# What should I start designing first from the given design doc?

Tags: java, uml

Using the following UML diagram, I need to implement the five classes in the black boxes in Java.

I am new to inheritance, so with this design what would be the best class to start with?

I know open arrow means *inheritance*, but does the other diamond shape arrow means it *composes* without belonging to class?

Comment: is this homework? if so, pretty sure this is covered by whatever book or reader or syllabus you're working off of. If not, and this is "work", this is the kind of thing to ask colleagues, or if it's a student job, your mentor.

Answer (score 0):

Here a link to explain different associations types:

http://creately.com/blog/diagrams/class-diagram-relationships/

http://agilemodeling.com/style/classDiagram.htm

Composition:
Strong relationship of composition, for example a car is composed from engine,weels... if we destroy one of the objects the composed object(the car) is destroyed.
In your example your signage is strongly composed from 1..* FormatedTexts .

Answer (score 0):

Start with implementing `FormattedText`, `Signings`, `ShowList` and then subclassing that with  `CategorizedShowList`.

The hollow diamond describes a shared aggregation. That means the `Signings` maintains a list of `FormattedText` objects which have a life of their own. So if the `Signings` removes the reference the `FormattedText` objects will still live on.

In contrast the composite aggregation has a filled diamond. When the reference is dropped the object will also die.